# The effect of velocity on the $g$-force applied to the pilot

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, aircraft

In a level flight (not maneuvering), if an aircraft increases its velocity from Mach 0 to Mach 10, how much  $g$-force is applied to the pilot? Is that any equation for it?

Comment: G force is zero if velocity isnt changing, even if you are going fast. g only comes from acceleration, outlined in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know over what period $t$ in seconds that the speed went from $0$ to Mach 10. You also need to convert the speed equivalent of Mach 10 into $ms^{-1}$, and call this speed $v$.

From here you would calculate the acceleration$^1$  $$a=\frac{v}{t}$$ and noting that $9.8ms^{-2}=1g$, then $$\frac{a}{9.8}=Xg$$ where $X$ is the g-value you are looking for.

$^1$ You stated “level flight not manoeuvring” and this method assumes that the acceleration $a$ is constant, i.e., $$\frac{d^3 x}{dt^3}=\frac{da}{dt}=0$$ or zero “jerk”, so it will probably yield an accurate measure of the real g-force experienced by the pilot.

Comment: Minor nit - this assumes constant acceleration.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  This would be a valid method to calculate the average acceleration over the time period, though;  you'd just need to be clear that you mean average acceleration rather than instantaneous.